# Running SSH without encryption or authentication

Tags: docker, ssh, terminal, server, ipython

## My Problem

I would like to run iPython from a daemonized Docker container in interactive mode from the host computer. SSH seems like a good choice, but I do not need any authentication, encryption, or key exchange - merely executing an interactive shell inside the container.

## My Question

How can I run an SSH server without authentication or encryption, just as a way to tun a remote terminal?

Comment: does `docker exec -ti` or `telnet` solve your problem?

Comment: Might be. Didn't consider `docker exec` for a daemonized container. Will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what you need is to enter the container, if so, just execute a bash shell with docker exec:

```
docker exec -ti my-running-container /bin/bash
```

or with docker attach

```
docker attach my-running-container
```

You might need to change the command to /bin/sh if you're running an alpine container instead of Fedora or Ubuntu.

On the other hand you should NEVER allow unencrypted connections to anything shell related.